# Is Revelation 3:16 a warning about the possibility of losing one's salvation?

Tags: revelation, authorial-intent, soteriology, figure-of-speech

Revelation 3:14-22 (ESV):

> 14 “And to the angel of the church in Laodicea write: ‘The words of the Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of God's creation.
>
> 15 “‘I know your works: you are neither cold nor hot. Would that you were either cold or hot! 16 **So, because you are lukewarm, and neither hot nor cold, I will spit you out of my mouth**. 17 For you say, I am rich, I have prospered, and I need nothing, not realizing that you are wretched, pitiable, poor, blind, and naked. 18 I counsel you to buy from me gold refined by fire, so that you may be rich, and white garments so that you may clothe yourself and the shame of your nakedness may not be seen, and salve to anoint your eyes, so that you may see. 19 Those whom I love, I reprove and discipline, so be zealous and repent. 20 Behold, I stand at the door and knock. If anyone hears my voice and opens the door, I will come in to him and eat with him, and he with me. 21 The one who conquers, I will grant him to sit with me on my throne, as I also conquered and sat down with my Father on his throne. 22 He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches.’”

If Jesus spits someone out of His mouth, does it follow that:

- they were inside Jesus's body in the first place?
- they were saved in the first place?
- they were expelled from Jesus's body?
- they are no longer saved?
- they lost their salvation?
- salvation can be lost?

---

Related BHSE question: [What does Jesus mean by "hot", "cold" and "lukewarm" in Revelation 3:16?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76203/what-does-jesus-mean-by-hot-cold-and-lukewarm-in-revelation-316)

Related CSE question: [How do those who believe that salvation cannot be lost interpret Revelation 3:14-22?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91039/50422)

Comment: Yes - see my answer here >>  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76198/are-john-151-11-and-revelation-314-22-referring-to-the-same-group-of-people

Comment: No - see my answer here >> https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/how-do-those-who-believe-that-salvation-cannot-be-lost-interpret-revelation-314/91049#91049

Comment: You have asked very many Qs, all related to this subject you keep going on about, "Can a Christian lose their salvation?" or words to that effect. You carefully re-word your Qs to make it look like a fresh Q but it's the same old topic. You even give links to similar Qs - your own Qs, in the main. By now you must have received over a hundred answers, some saying Yes, they can, others saying No. Is it not time you collated all your answers, reviewed them, and came to a conclusion of your own? Otherwise, why do you keep going on about this?

Comment: @Anne - if you believe they are duplicates, feel free to vote to close this question as a duplicate of another question.

Comment: As I said, you carefully re-word each Q - to give yourself enough wiggle room to avoid new Qs being direct duplicates of old ones. But a recurrent theme pervades them all. You are pursuing a topic and seeking differing opinions. You know how to do that within the 'rules' of Stack. I'm just letting you know that others can see the bigger picture here. But keep on expanding that picture if you like. Just don't expect some of us to keep providing the background material for your portrayal.

Answer (score 2):

The Revelation of Jesus Christ was given to the Apostle John as a vision concerning events leading up to the second coming of Jesus Christ.  It is a warning, not just to the seven churches in Asia back then, but to the church now.  ***It is interpreted spiritually.***

John was commanded to write down the words addressed to the churches so the individuals in each church could read what they otherwise would never have known.  They would then be made aware of the judgment of the Lord by the angel, for good or ill, upon that church.

***Judgment begins at the house of God.***  With the warning addressed to each of the seven churches comes the promise that those who overcome will become heirs of the promise and heirs of glory.  First, the cause of the approbation must be overcome.  They read the message, but they must hear the Spirit and change their ways.  It was not too late back then, and it is not too late here and now.

You have already received good answers about the meaning of hot, cold, and lukewarm as applied to the church in Laodicea here: [What does Jesus mean by "hot", "cold" and "lukewarm" in Revelation 3:16?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76203/what-does-jesus-mean-by-hot-cold-and-lukewarm-in-revelation-316)

***“I will spit you out of my mouth” is a figure of speech.***  Lukewarm water is unpalatable.  Spiritually speaking so is lukewarm faith and worship.  Spiritually speaking it is like sitting on the fence, neither one thing nor the other.  That sort of wishy-washy approach is unacceptable.  ***However, along with the warning comes the promise that those who overcome are spared the judgment.***

Any person claiming to be a Christian who consistently engages in and enjoys sin without heeding Christ and His Word reveals that he was never born again.  Jesus told such people, “You belong to your father, the devil, and you want to carry out your father’s desire” (John 8:44).  The child of God, on the other hand, no longer craves the gratification of sin but desires to know, love, and glorify his or her Father.  Clearly, just being baptised does not make someone a child of God.  Likewise, living a life of sin and and failing to follow Jesus’ commands shows that person is no child of God.

Those who are spiritually alive, who have been re-born and are part of the spiritual body of Christ have the assurance of the indwelling Holy Spirit in God’s promises: “To all who did receive him, to those who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God” (John 1:12).

When one is saved, he/she has been born again, spiritually renewed, and is now a child of God by right of new birth.  "Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation: the old has gone, the new has come!" (2 Corinthians 5:17).  Jesus promised that he would not lose any that have been given to him by his Father (John 6:39).  It is the indwelling Spirit of God and of Jesus Christ that confirms they have been accepted and are heirs to the promises (Romans 8:15; Galatians 4:6).

There is a difficulty in answering your questions by linking the subject of losing salvation to John’s vision and then attempting to come up with a human interpretation.  Pay heed to this warning:

> I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this book: If anyone adds anything to them, God will add to him the plagues described in this book.  And if anyone takes words away from this book of prophecy, God will take away from him his share in the tree of life and in the holy city, which are described in this book (Revelation 22:18-19 NIV).

He who promises is faithful and true (Revelation19:11).

Answer (score 1):

It’s unlikely that Jesus would contradict Himself with salvation by saying:

> “*So, because you are lukewarm, and neither hot nor cold, I will spit
> you out of my mouth*.”

Then turn around in the next verse and say:

> “For you say, I am rich, I have prospered, and I need nothing, not
> realizing that you are wretched, pitiable, poor, blind, and naked. 18
> **I counsel you to buy from me gold refined by fire, so that you may be rich, and white garments so that you may clothe yourself and the
> shame of your nakedness may not be seen**, and salve to anoint your
> eyes, so that you may see.
>
> 19 **Those whom I love, I reprove and discipline, so be zealous and
> repent**.

Why would Jesus say in effect  “I am going to damn you, but wait… hang on, I will counsel you to buy from me…”

It seems that there is something else going on here, Jesus in Rev 3:16 may be referring to discipline as opposed to condemnation, since Romans 8 teaches no condemnation (Rom 8:1, to no separation (Rom 8:38-39) for those **in Christ**.  Which is a position that all true believers have by adoption: (Romans 8:14-16).

Revelation 3:19 also makes it clear that as many as Jesus’ loves He reproves and disciplines.  The scripture makes it clear that God is slow to anger (Psalms 103:8-9).

It’s highly unlikely that Jesus would abandon discipline and spit people out of His mouth into condemnation.

Those who are born again are over-comers despite the warnings in Revelation: (2:7, 2:11, 2:17, 2:26, 3:5, 3:12, 3:21).

We can read the warnings at face value, they are real threatenings, but God does not have contradictions in His written Word, for we read:

> “**For whatever is born of God overcomes the world**; and this is the
> victory that has overcome the world—our faith. **Who is the one who
> overcomes the world, but he who believes that Jesus is the Son of
> God?**” ‭‭1 John‬ ‭5‬:‭4‬-‭5‬

‭It is more probable that Jesus spitting people out His mouth is a means of correction given the following words as argued already above.  If they are true believers, Jesus would correct them (Rev 3:19).

Lastly, Jesus has a mission to lose none out of all that the Father has given Him for eternal life, (**John 6:37-40**) as Lesley already noted. This should make us reconsider Jesus as a mighty savior and not a flippant one.

Can Jesus save us from our sins, but not the power of indwelling sin?  Jesus will save us from both, for we have His fear in our hearts to enable us to never depart from Him: (Jeremiah 32:40).

We must however, keep the faith (Colossians 1:21-23) while we are being kept by God: (1 Peter 1:5).